# How to detect Phonegap app launch (not including page refresh)

Tags: javascript, cordova

How do I check if the Phonegap application was just launched. I don't want the index.html page reload to count as an app launch. Only when the app is launched when the user clicks the icon of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using a multi-page app (as opposed to writing a Single Page App). I would expect that you could just listen for the deviceready event and track the index page based on that, as the event only fires when the app is first being launched and won't fire again until the app is stopped and launched again.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    // track index.html page load here
}
```

Documentation:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready